# include pieces of html code in the index file.html

Tags: html, include

In the repository [responsive-components](https://github.com/philipwalton/responsive-components) there is a file [index.html](https://github.com/philipwalton/responsive-components/blob/master/app/templates/index.html).
It uses the following constructions:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

{% include 'nav.html' %}

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

with their help, included external files: '**header.html**', '**nav.html**', '**footer.html**' and much more.

this code works fine on GitHub Pages (where PHP not supported): [working example](https://philipwalton.github.io/responsive-components/).

How it works?

I assume that it makes some script. But I found information only about include in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked project uses a templating engine called [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/).
You can read more about how the includes work in [the documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I also found that this syntax is described in the [documentation for Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/). Nunjucks is a more simple solution in contrast to Jekyll?

Comment: They're two different things. Jekyll is a complete [static site generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system#Static_site_generators) while Nunjucks is 'just' a JavaScript templating engine.